# Deploying old app versions with elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services

I recently deployed a new version of my app to an elastic beanstalk environment and I want to revert to an older version, as we're not quite ready for the new version.

I go to the EB ApplicationVersions page for my application, choose the checkbox next to the version I want and press deploy. After confirming, I can see the logs of the application restarting. But it is always the newest version of the app. It never deploys the version I want.

I've also tried using the CLI `eb deploy -l label`. It seems to work, but still - the app restarts with the newest version always.

Is this standard behaviour? Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `eb deploy --version YOURVERSION`.